# A property claimed to start before zero, at -512! Resetting it to zero, and hoping for the best

Tags: java

When I read a MS word document Header (.doc), I got this exception:

```
"A property claimed to start before zero, at -512! Resetting it to zero, and hoping for the best"
```

I use this library `poi-scratchpad-3.2-final-20081019`, and I use this code for reading:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class ReadDocFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
File file = null;
WordExtractor extractor = null ;
try {

   file = new File("c:\\New.doc");
   FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
   HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
   extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
   String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
   for(int i=0;i<fileData.length;i++){
     if(fileData[i] != null)
       System.out.println(fileData[i]);
   }
}
catch(Exception exep){}
  }
}
```

Comment: I enjoy any program that "hopes for the best". That said; we could use more details on exactly what caused this exception, is it reading all documents or just this one? What code did you use to read it? etc etc

Comment: not constructive i know - but you could also say - using MSWord, hoping for the best. :)

Comment: Ahhh!! edit it into the question if at all possible

Comment: I'm not seeing that exception anywhere in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused by a [poi file](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hwpf/model/PropertyNode.java):

```
protected PropertyNode(int fcStart, int fcEnd, Object buf)
{
    _cpStart = fcStart;
    _cpEnd = fcEnd;
    _buf = buf;

    if(_cpStart < 0) {
        _logger.log(POILogger.WARN, "A property claimed to start before zero, at " + _cpStart + "! Resetting it to zero, and hoping for the best");
      _cpStart = 0;
    }
    //more code
```

As you can see in the code the logger creates this error when _cpStart is smaller than 0 which in your case would be: -512. This means the PropertyNode method is being called with fcStart = -512.

As for what is calling it with -512:

> The -512 originates in a calculation done in org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.
>   CHPFormattedDiskPage, where getStart(x) returns 1536 and fcMin is 2048.

As taken from: [Bug report](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@poi.apache.org/msg03442.html)

This warning is logged when you create an instance of HWPFDocument and is a known bug that will not affect the functionality (as _cpStart is set to 0).

Comment: So hoping for the best really was the right course of action, who'd have thought it

Comment: how i can change it in poi file 
i don't understand how to solve this!

Comment: @WithoutName You can't change the poi file. You have to accept the message :(